# How to build with the final export value?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a large ts data file:

`data.ts` :

```
export data = [
  ... // huge data 
]
```

the `lib.ts` just use some of the `data`:

```
import { data } from './data.ts';

const fitteredData = data.splice(0,2) // only use some of them

export { fitteredData };
```

I use `fitteredData`  in my vue component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { fitteredData } from "./lib";
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ fitteredData }}</div>
</template>
```

After run `pnpm build`, I find all of the data in `data.ts` are builded in final file. How to make the final file only with the `fitteredData`?

How to make the final file only with the `fitteredData`, to make the final builded files smaller.

Comment: `vite` doesn't run your code to see what you are doing - so you can't import a huge file and expect any bundler to know that you only want a part of it. since your code only wants part of the data, then why can't you just have `data.ts` contain only the data you require?

Comment: I guess you could have a pre-build step that creates a "filtereddata.ts" any you import that, but without seeing what `data.ts` is, there's no way to tell if that's even possibl

Answer (score 2):

**lib/filter-data.ts**: ***<sup>1</sup>***

```
import fs from 'fs'
import { data } from './data'
fs.writeFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/filteredData.json`,
  JSON.stringify(data.splice(0, 2), null, 2)
)
```

In your vue component:

```
// import { filteredData } from "./lib";
import filteredData from "./lib/filteredData.json"
```

And run

```
npx ts-node ./filter-data.ts
```

whenever you need to rewrite `filteredData.json` (adjust path accordingly).
Also note you can place this command in your `package.json`'s `scripts` and run it prior to any other existing script:

Example: ***<sup>2</sup>***

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": ...,
    "buiild": ...,
    "test": ...,
    "filter-data": "yarn --cwd lib npx ts-node ./filter-data.ts",
    "predev": "yarn filter-data",
    "prebuild": "yarn filter-data",
    "pretest": "yarn filter-data"
  }
}
```

Your build will only contain the filtered data (contents of `filteredData.json`).

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - you don't have to write it as a `.json` file, you can write it as a `.ts` file, just make sure the output is valid TS
***<sup>2</sup>*** - replace `yarn` with `npm run` if you use `npm`